# Excel: Is there a registry setting to suppress the warning messages when saving spreadsheets in CSV format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I work with many CSV files, and am constantly annoyed by the Excel dialog that pops up when I try to save a file:

"[your spreadsheet] may contain features that are not compatible with CSV (Comma Delimited).  Do you want to keep the workbook in this format?"

My answer is always going to be YES.  Is there a registry setting to suppress this confirmation dialog?

Comment: Probably not.  Is a macro an option for you?

Comment: There's an Excel AddIn (with source) for my related question [How to Export -- not Save As -- to another format?](http://superuser.com/questions/978228/how-to-export-not-save-as-to-another-format) that can help with this.

Comment: In office version 1611 Build 7571.2075 (personal subscription), I see a checkbox setting under File/Options/Save, "Show data loss warning when editing comma delimited files (*.csv)"  However, it is unchecked and I still get the warning. On another computer that's on the deferred channel with version 16.0.6965.2115 (work subscription), this option is not available, yet I somehow got it to stop pestering me when saving csv. I'll contribute an answer if I ever figure it out for real, but I'm hoping they're in the process of implementing a functional solution with that checkbox.

Answer (score 6):

This is a common problem all Excel users suffer. I think, the only way to do that is to use a macro. For example:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ThisWorkbook
    .SaveAs Left(.FullName, Len(.FullName) - 3) & "csv", xlCSV
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: would `Left(.FullName, Len(.FullName) - 3) & "csv"` mean in case of a `foobar.xlsx` a new filename `foobar.csv`, right? this omits the save dialog, and having custom names, right? in that case it is worth to note that if your *workbook* 'file' contains multiple *worksheet* 'tabs', then CSV can only can save the active one. and this would be better if addressed with the naming in my opinion, if possible! (unfortunately not a macro guy myself yet)

Comment: how does one add this macro...?

Answer (score 4):

I have Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus and today I noticed for the first time ever, Excel asking me if I want to disable CSV save notifications. I realize not everyone has Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus subscription but if you do, this might help. My version shows "Version 1609 (Build 7369.2118).

If you visit this link: [Disable CSV Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqLwL.jpg)

It will show you where to find it. It's in:

`File > Options > Save > Under 'Save workbooks' find checkbox that says "Show data loss warning when editing comma delimited files (*.csv)"`

Comment: hmm. I don't see it in my excel. Just for that I wish I could upgrade

Answer (score 2):

I addressed it with [ClickOff](https://web.archive.org/web/20150715055325/http://www.johanneshuebner.com/en/clickoff.shtml). The site it was hosted on is down, but I uploaded it [here](http://thompcha.com/mirror/clickoff.exe).

Comment: Worked for me. Looks like his link moved [here](http://johanneshuebner.com/quickcms/index.html%3Fde_downloads,2.html). I downloaded the program, assigned it to English, and went through the prompts in Excel using Ctrl+Alt+D and now it auto clicks on the prompts!

Comment: ok interesting solution but you need this program to run in the background.