# Can I disable Excel's warning when saving CSV files?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, office-for-mac, microsoft-excel-2011

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel: Is there a registry setting to suppress the warning messages when saving spreadsheets in CSV format?](https://superuser.com/questions/73275/excel-is-there-a-registry-setting-to-suppress-the-warning-messages-when-saving)

Excel always says

> ...may contain features that are not compatible with CSV

when saving CSV files. Can this be disabled, specifically in Office / Excel 2011 on Mac?

Comment: I doubt it can be, that warning has been bugging people for decades...

Comment: Maybe this solution?: http://superuser.com/questions/73275/excel-is-there-a-registry-setting-to-suppress-the-warning-messages-when-saving