# How to Export -- not Save As -- to another format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, export

How can I Export a sheet or table or selection to another file format *without changing the currently active document* ?

Our primary data operation environment is in Excel, where extensive use of formatting and formulas is used to get our desired results. The results are then saved as `.CSV` for interoperability with other programs.

When "File >> **Save As** >> Save as type >> CSV" is used the .csv file is created **and** the active document is changed to `saved_file.csv`. There are some warnings about losing functionality and formatting with this new format, but otherwise the user interface is unchanged. There are bold and italics, different fonts and sizes, background cell fills, defined table ranges and so on. All the formulas in the cells remain intact.

This is a disaster waiting to happen. The user is gets back to work, lulled into thinking everything is normal, soon forgets the current format doesn't support any magic, and carries on doing Important Stuff(tm). Lunch time arrives, they close Excel, slap Yes twice to annoying dialogs that aren't-read-because-they-see-them-all-the-time, and head out the door. ...After lunch user comes back and realizes all the work between initial Save As and Exit is gone.

"File >> *Export*", unfortunately, is just another navigation route to "Save As", also changing the active document to "some_file.csv".

What we need is to export some data to another file type and keep the active document "our-real-data.xlsx".

How can this be done? And added to menu or ribbon for one-click execution?

How can it be shared with everyone in the organisation? 
(without asking individual users to open a VBA editor etc.)

Comment: Try taking a look here, seems like they create a button and export the data using VBA. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140725234224-54506939-excel-to-csv-export-instead-of-save-as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What we need is to export some data to another file type and keep the active document "our-real-data.xlsx".

## [CSV_tools.xla](http://ge.tt/4oqfjWO2/v/0)

I've put together a quick VBA Add-In which exports as CSV since you mentioned it. I tried to use as less code as possible so new users can understand it more easily.

### What does it

- Add-in asks where to save the CSV. Default folder is the folder where the XLS is saved in
- Add-in automatically detects if a comma or semicolon should be used as separator regarding to your regional system settings
- All values of the currently active Excel sheet are exported to a new CSV file which is named after the XLS file
- The existing XLS does not get touched in any way

### Installation

1. Download the [Add-In](http://ge.tt/4oqfjWO2/v/0) and save it to under `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns`
2. Open Excel and activate it under

   - Excel 2003: Menu bar → Tools → Add-ins
   - Excel 2007: Excel Options → Add-Ins → Go To
   - Excel 2010-13: File tab → Options → Add-Ins → Go To
3. Restart Excel and look at your menu bar

   [image]

### VBA code

```vb
Function ExportCSV()

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    On Error Resume Next
    ChDrive (ActiveWorkbook.Path)
    ChDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path)
    strName = fso.GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
    On Error GoTo 0

    strFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(strName, "CSV Files,*.csv", 1)
    delimiter = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
    If Not strFilename = False Then

        Open strFilename For Append As #1

        For Each rngRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
            arr2D = rngRow
            arr1D = Application.Index(arr2D, 1, 0)
            strRow = Join(arr1D, delimiter)
            Print #1, strRow
        Next

        Close #1
    End If

End Function
```

#### Automatic updates for different users

Once every user has enabled the Add-in in their Excel (cannot be automated), you can copy new `.xla` file version via network share, Robocopy or similar tools. But this should be a separate question since there are too many different ways to solve the issue.

---

For the VBA geeks, the most interesting part is

```
arr2D = rngRow
arr1D = Application.Index(arr2D, 1, 0)
strRow = Join(arr1D, delimiter)
```

which converts a range (a single row in our case) to a 2D array, then to a 1D array and finally to a single string using the Join() function

Comment: Thank you for this. It works as described on most sheets I have, but on one it yields "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch", after which pressing [debug] lands me a the line `arr1D = Application.Index(arr2D, 1, 0)`. Sorry I can't share the problem one. I'll try and generate a lorem-ipsum version for testing.

Comment: @mattwilkie Could it be that the sheet is emtpy? Pay attention on how the data is structured on this particular sheet. All in 1 row? multiple rows? All in one column? Multiple columns?

Comment: No not empty. 675 rows, columns to V. ... it has something to do with content: one of the columns has embedded html snippets as text, e.g. `<div class="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:#1F497D;mso-fareast-language:EN-US">Review proposal...`. After removing that column CSV Tools export works. The regular save-as-filetype csv menu route has no problem with the html column in place.

Comment: so much for being lazy and not wanting to use ftp (and a strike against tinyupload.com). Try this instead: http://files.environmentyukon.ca/matt/CSV_Tools/

Comment: suggestion: pre-populate default filename with Sheet Name/Title

Comment: I still have [no solution for cells with more than 255 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32978800/935614)

Comment: If any of the cells contain the delimiter inside the value, using just Join(arr1D, delimiter) will produce an incorrect CSV - you'll need to enclose it with double-quotes. Additionally, if cell value has been enclosed with double quotes and the value itself contains a double quote - this one needs to be escaped with a second double quote.
See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180 for details on the CSV requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Teach the user to open a copy of that data.

When selecting an Office document, you can right-click the icon, and click New. This creates a new document/sheet/presentation, based on the original. The users can export from that, just by doing a Save As

I hope you also have good backups though if you're this worried...

Comment: This doesn't really work, because the exports are to capture various stages of analysis, snapshots if you will. Bob does X,Y,Z ...then exports to CSV, followed by doing A,B,C ...then exports. Rinse, lather. repeat. If open-as-copy is used all the "doing" in the middle is discarded (not saved in the xls file).