# Install Office Store app in offline Desktop Office

Tags: microsoft-office

How can I install an app from the [Microsoft Office Store](https://store.office.com/) in the desktop version of Excel/Word/... 2013 that does not have a *Connected Service* to the store?

Note this question isn't about how to link desktop office to the store, it's about how to get and use apps in desktop office in a business where policy says "do not link external services".

Another way of wording the question is *"how do I download an Office Store app for offline install?"*

[image: Add service dialog]

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: Don't your business policies also say please ask IT if you need to install software? Are you allowed to use Google (that is a link to an external service) ;)

Comment: Note that [su] is also a link to an external service. You should not be posting here ...

Comment: mmm. Looks like using "link" confused the issue. "Connected service" might have been better. @DavidPostill there's a world of difference between a person opening a program and going to example.domain.org and carrying out some kind of work there and installing a service that operates in the background without user intervention or knowledge on it's own schedule and carrying out opaque tasks. In any case debating the wisdom of such policy is not the topic.

Comment: @Ramhound, ...because I have already [successfully installed](http://superuser.com/a/978282/16966) other Add-ins by downloading a file and adding them. I suppose another way of wording the question is _"how do I download an Office Store app for offline install?"_

Comment: They are not add-ons....they req the store

Comment: @Ramhound eh? The Store calls them that: "To use this **add-in**, you’ll need ... Excel 2013 Service Pack 1 or later ..."  [emph. added] ([ref](https://store.office.com/WA104379169.aspx#))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: *you can't get there from here*. Thank you @Ramhound for asking the question that redirected my searches that eventually revealed understanding, even though it's not what I wanted.

The architecture of an Office "app" is predicated on active connection to an external server; see diagram. This is quite different from the "Add-Ins" I've used up until now ([example](https://superuser.com/a/978282/16966)) which follow the more traditional activation route of download files, unpack, install. My confusion was spawned in part by the fact that Microsoft also uses the "add-in" term for apps in the Store.

> **Manifest + webpage = an app for Office**
>
> [image: app structure diagram]

The same [Overview of apps for Office 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219429.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) page that gives us the graphic above also outlines how to create your own file based Distribution Point repository from which to install apps. So it is possible, technically, to use app-add-ins without connecting to the Office Store service.

Practically it's not going to happen without support and commitment from the IT department and the developers of the app you're interested in. First with IT in order to set the trust relationship with the distribution point, and the server which the app is communicating with. Secondly with the developers in order to supply the raw app manifest file.